# Numerically find all zeros of multivariate function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, numerical-methods, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do I find all zeros of a multivariate function  , i.e. f(x1,x2,x2,...xn)=0 numerically?
I don't know exact analytic form of f , but can numerically compute f at every point on its domain.

*Example*: Given a matrix A=[i , a; 3+i , 9], I have to find **all** complex a such that A has an complex eigenvalue with arguement 37 degrees?

Here *i* is sqrt(-1).

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the exact analytic form for this example? To compute the eigenvalues:

$|\mathbf{A}-\lambda\mathbf{I}|=0 \rightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{cc} i-\lambda & a\\3+i&9-\lambda \end{array}\right]=0$

So you need to find the complex values with argument 37 degree:
$\lambda=|\lambda| e^{i\angle 37^{\circ}}$. Plugging this:

$(i-|\lambda| e^{i\angle 37^{\circ}})(9-|\lambda| e^{i\angle 37^{\circ}})-a(3+i)=0$. Therefore:

$a=\frac{(i-|\lambda| e^{i\angle 37^{\circ}})(9-|\lambda| e^{i\angle 37^{\circ}})}{3+i}$

Comment: But if the array A is large and I want to compute all values of a numerically, then how to proceed?
Actually, I am required to submit a numerical solution to the problem, not an analytical one.